# Calling Index function in VBA to retrieve an array of data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have this worksheet.

[image]

In another worksheet's Activate event, I want to retrieve all the rows for a specified year and week.

In VBA I am able to get the desired sheet. How can I call the index function to retrieve all the rows for a given year and week?

I must print columns from these rows on the new worksheet.

I have a call to the INDEX function in the workbook that looks like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('L5 Data'!$C$6:$C$104000,SUMPRODUCT(('L5 Data'!$A$6:$A$104000=$B$1)*('L5 Data'!$B$6:$B$104000=$B$2)*('L5 Data'!$F$6:$F$104000=E$6)*ROW('L5 Data'!$6:$104000))-5),"")
```

I modified it to look like this:

```
        comment_date = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(line_data_sheet.Range(C6:C104000), Application.WorksheetFunction.SUMPRODUCT((line_data_sheet.Range(A6:A104000)=year)*(line_data_sheet.Range(B6:B104000)=week)*('L5 Data'!$F$6:$F$104000=D$3)*ROW(line_data_sheet.Range($6:$104000)))-5),"")
```

In the original call to the INDEX function, I specify three criteria (year, week, machine) to retrieve a specific column for one row of data.

But in VBA I only want to specify two criteria (year, week) and loop through all the matching rows (machines) to retrieve specific columns.

How do I modify the line of code "comment_date" to get this?

Answer (score 0):

*Since you have not uploaded the VBA Code you are trying with so that I would like to suggest the below written code to try with your data.*

```
Dim row as Long

With Sheets("Line_Data_Sheet").Range("A6:C104000"))
    For row = 6 To .Rows.Count
        If .Cells(row, ColName).Value Like Criteria1 And .Cells(row, ColName).Value Like Criteria2 Then

            Debug.Print .Cells(row, valueCol)
        End if
    Next
End With
```

**NB:** *You need to replace ColName and Criteria1 & 2 with your's.*

or you can use in this way also,

```
For Each cell In Range("A6:B104000")
If cell.Value = "Year" And cell.Value = "Week" Then
    i = cell.Row
    Range("E" & i).Formula = "IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(line_data_sheet.Range(C6:C104000), Application.WorksheetFunction.SUMPRODUCT((line_data_sheet.Range(A6:A104000)=year)*(line_data_sheet.Range(B6:B104000)=week)*ROW(line_data_sheet.Range($6:$104000)))-5),"")"
End If
Next
```

*Hope this help you.*